# Split array by regular expression in Node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string, split

I'm using https://github.com/joyent/node-strsplit to split the text extracted from a file. I need to extract the data between double curly braces. Following will be some sample text in the file.

**I am living in  {{address||address of current property owner}} under the name {{name}} and my id (nic) will be {{nic||National Identity Number}})**

Here, I want to extract the text inside double opening and closing curly braces. For example the ultimate array should be like,
**['address||address of current property owner','name','nic||National Identity Number']**

For this, I tried to use the following Regex patterns,

```
/{{(.*?)}}/
/{{([^}]*)}}/
/\{{([^}]+)\}}/
```

Following will my code.

```
var pattern = '/{{(.*?)}}/';
var arr=strsplit(sample_text, pattern);
```

Please help me out for finalizing the approach. Cheers !!

Updated:

```
var results = [], re = /{{([^}]+)}}/g, text;

  while(item = re.exec(text)) {
       results.push(item[1]);
  }
```

Comment: Why not use `/{{(.*?)}}/g.exec(sample_text)` and get all Group 1 values in a loop? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with `match()` and strip the brackets:

```js
var str = "I am living in {{address||address of current property owner}} under the name {{name}} and my id (nic) will be {{nic||National Identity Number}})";
var result = str.match(/{{.*?}}/g).map(function(x){return x.slice(2,-2)});
console.log(result)
```